# How to improve the performance of panorama control in Windows Phone

Tags: performance, windows-phone-7, panorama-control

I am building a Windows Phone app with a panorama control, which has four PanoramaItems. Each PanoramaItem has a listbox, containing some listboxitems.

If one of the those listboxitems was selected ,the app would navigated to the another page, when I press the BackKey, the app usually **took one second** to go back the Mainpage. There was no time-comsuming event on `Loaded()` and `NavigatedTo()`.

So the problem may be the ListBox? But there should be data-cache of listbox, and if so I can't find out the cause.